# knockoutjs subscribe not firing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following client-side code:

```
var ProfileManager = function () {
    self.SelectedLanguage = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedLanguage.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert("The person's new name is " + newValue);
    });
    var bindUIwithViewModel = function (viewModel) {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    };
}
```

and I later do `bindUIwithViewModel(self);`.

and a HTML select bound to `SelectedLanguage`:

```
<select id="selectAvailableLanguages" class="form-control language-select" data-bind="options: AvailableLanguages, optionsText: 'Code', value : SelectedLanguage"></select>
```

The `select` gets populated successfully, the value inside `SelectedLanguage` observable changes, but the `alert` just won't show up. Any ideas?

Also, don't know if related but the `observe` array inside `__ko.mapping_` is an `array[0]`..

Comment: Do you reference `SelectedLanguage` anywhere else other than that binding?  For example, are you inadvertently doing `SelectedLanguage = ko.observable` elsewhere and changing it to be a different observable, rather than updating the existing one?  If you do this, the subscription will not fire as it's on the "wrong" observable.

Comment: I am updating the value (or that's what I think I do) using self.SelectedLanguage(newValue). Should this influence the subscribing mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q2g60L2/). Note, "AvailableLanguages" and "SelectedLanguage" properties should exist in the same context, i.e. belong the binded view model.

I've modified your JS code:

```
var ProfileManager = function () {
    self.SelectedLanguage = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedLanguage.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert("The person's new name is " + JSON.stringify(newValue));
    });
    self.AvailableLanguages = [ { Code: 'c++', Person: 'John' }, { Code: 'c#', Person: 'Mark' } ]

}

ko.applyBindings(new ProfileManager());
```